# What can be the reasons that RNN generates very short results?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm struggling with creating One2Seq model with Keras. The base concept is to generate Instagram comments based on the array of tags.

Example input: [0,0,1,1] - #dog #animal

Example outputs: ['That's a nice doggo!', 'Surely he likes to eat']

I have collected ~10k comments and related tags and used this dataset for various RNN models. However, no matter how long I'll train them, usually I get only 1-word output (rest of the sequence is padding). What can be the possible reasons of such behaviour?

Dataset is divided into 9k training and 1k validation set. The most latest model is based on such structure:

```py
model = keras.Sequential([

    keras.layers.Embedding(input_size, 5, input_length=8),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.RepeatVector(10),
    keras.layers.LSTM(512, return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    keras.layers.LSTM(512, return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(4055, activation='softmax'), input_shape=(10, 512,))
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy', 'categorical_crossentropy'])
```

I use 5-D embedding for the tags array (100-word vocab), flattening layer and repeat vector to feed the LSTM. 4055 is the output word vocabulary for generated sentences.

Validation loss starts to increase at ~50th epoch. However, example output looks like:

this padding padding padding ...

i padding padding padding ...

:) padding padding padding ...

wow ! padding padding padding ...

It's a bit strange since more than 50% of the comments are longer than 10 words.

Comment: Few questions I have, Isn't the embedding size 5 a little too small? Have you tried with larger sizes (e.g. 100)? What's the final validation accuracy you get? Did you check if your training data is properly preprocessed ?

Comment: I took 5 dim out of the blue - I've looked at the Glove model which has very large vocabulary (mine is only different 100 tags) and can be represented as a 200D, so I chose something smaller.

About the accuracy - it's somewhere about 0,49. Actually it keeps rising steadily but the validation loss starts to rise, so I assume that's the point to stop.

What do you mean by properly preprocessed? Initial dataset contains about 20k comments - I've filtered out non-english languages, dropped comments that contain only @user shout etc. In the end there's only half of the initial state.